# Using Services in non-Angular Classes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am using Angular v7.3.5 and I want to use a Service in a non-Angular class, something like this:

foo.model.ts

```ts
import { Foo2Service } from './foo2.service';
// Definition for FooClass (a model)
export class FooClass {
    constructor(args: any) {
        // Do something with args
    }

    func1() {
        // -----> Use Foo2Service here <-------
    }
}
```

foo2.service.ts

```ts
export class Foo2Service {
    // Service code
    constructor(private bar: BarService) {}

    init() {
        // Code that returns something
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```ts
import { FooClass } from './foo.model.ts';

export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        const foo = new FooClass('bar');
        console.log(foo.func1());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do so? If yes, what is the best way to do it?

**NOTE:** I tried to use the `Injector` class provided by Angular but it didn't work for me. So please help.

Comment: Where is this `bar`  instance coming from? (I am referring to code `new FooClass(bar);`)

Comment: @Igor Oh, sorry! It was intended to be a `string` or an `object`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Injector` should work:

Create the injector:

```ts
const injector = Injector.create({ 
  providers: [ 
    { provide: Foo2Service, deps:[] },
  ]
});
```

For the sake of the test, let's return the string `test` from your init function in service:

```ts
init() {
  return 'test';
}
```

for testing, in your class you would call `init` using the injector:

```ts
func1() {
  let myService = injector.get(Foo2Service);
  return myService.init();
}
```

and finally the component calling `func1`:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  const foo = new FooClass({});
  console.log(foo.func1()) // prints 'test'
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2komcp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: OK, now I know what I was doing wrong... Actually I had already did this, but not in 'Foo2Service'... Thanks, by the way...